# Entity Framework Datagridview filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I´m new to C# development, and have some questions.
I hope you help please.

I have 2 entities related many-to-many -  Movies and Genres.
I need to show all movies in a datagridView where movies.genres contains the genre selected in a listBoxGenres.

I try this code:

```
moviesDBEntities myContext = new moviesDBEntities();

var myQuery = from movie in myContext.Movies
               where movie.genre.Contains(ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem)
               select movie;


dgvMovies.Datasource = myQuery.ToList();
```

The problem is that a receive an exception error like this:

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem` contains in it?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
    lstBoxGenres.Datasource = myContext.Genres 
    lstBoxGenres.DisplayMember = " idGenre"; 
    lstBoxGenres.ValueMember = "Genre"; 

I dont have the ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem.Value property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx).

> Referencing a non-scalar variables, such as an entity, in a query is
>   not supported. When such a query executes, a NotSupportedException
>   exception is thrown with a message that states "Unable to create a
>   constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive types ('such as
>   Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Try rewording your query to use scalar variable (here I assume Genre entity has PK of Id):

```
var myQuery = from movie in myContext.Movies
          where movie.genre.Any(g=>g.Id == ((Genre)listBox.SelectedItem).Id)
          select movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use property of `ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem`, for example: `ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem.Value`

```
var myQuery = from movie in myContext.Movies
              where movie.genre.Contains(ListBoxGenres.SelectedItem.Value)
              select movie;
```